# Why does angular 1.5 routes break controllers?

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('CalendarTest')
      .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/signup', {
          templateUrl: '/signup.html'
        })
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
          templateUrl: '/login.html'
        })
        $routeProvider.when('/testPage', {
          templateUrl: '/testPage.html'
        })
        $routeProvider.when('/visitform', {
          templateUrl: '/visitform.html'
        })
      });
```

The router loads when index loads with out an error.

```
angular.module('formLoginApp', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('formLoginController', ['$scope', '$cookies', ($scope, $cookies) => {
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.password = '';
    $scope.update = (user) => {
      const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open('POST', 'http://localhost:4002/login', true);
      req.onload = (serverResponse) => {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
          if (req.status === 200) {
            $cookies.put("user", req.response);
          } else {
            console.log('no response');
          }
        } else {
          console.log('no response');
        }
      };
      req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate");
      req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      req.send(JSON.stringify(user));
    };
  }]);
```

when I try to access this page login.html, i get formLoginController is not a (and nothing here...).  I am not sure why this is going on.  I tried simplifying the issue and adding a controller from the docs but that also breaks.  How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't access templates like `'login.html` directly. You should be requesting `#/login`

Comment: also update to the latest version of chrome. You have used EcmaScript standards for defining functions. Maybe the browser doesn't support EcmaScript. Try writing pure JavaScript functions and see or transpile your code using babel or something